# Jasmine Karma Array.find is not a function

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using Jasmine for testing and Karma as my test runner.

I have a simple find method using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which is failing with error:

> TypeError: myns.dataList.find is not a function

This suggests it can't understand the function. I also have a polyfill for the method in the same file, and also have [an es6 shim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-es6-shim) installed on Node.

Using Chrome 51.0.2704

This is what I'm trying:

```
describe('the description', function() {
    it('should work', function() {

        jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/path/to/json/';
        myns.dataList = loadJSONFixtures('dataList.json');

        console.log(myns.dataList); /* all ok here, json is loaded */

        var theName = myns.dataList.find(function(entry) {
            return entry.name === selfName;
        });

        expect(2 + 2).not.toEqual(4); /* doesn't get here because of TypeError */
    });
});
```

**Note:** this works as it should when Jasmine is run directly from the browser

Answer (score 2):

May be it is a late reply, but this is something you could do to fix this issue. Call the following code before your test code is about to make a call to fin method.

```
    if (typeof Array.prototype.find !== 'function') {
        Array.prototype.find = function(iterator) {
            var list = Object(this);
            var length = list.length >>> 0;
            var thisArg = arguments[1];
            var value;

            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                value = list[i];
                if (iterator.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
                    return value;
                }
            }
            return undefined;    
        };
    }
```

This will check if there is no such method available (find) in the array definition, it will add one.

Originally posted here :  http://sehajpal.com/2016/10/missing-function-definitions-in-jasmine-karma-testing-not-a-function/

So, roughly, your code will look like (refactor as per your need) :

```
describe('the description', function() {
    it('should work', function() {

        jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/path/to/json/';
        myns.dataList = loadJSONFixtures('dataList.json');

        console.log(myns.dataList); /* all ok here, json is loaded */
        if (typeof Array.prototype.find !== 'function') {
            Array.prototype.find = function(iterator) {
                var list = Object(this);
                var length = list.length >>> 0;
                var thisArg = arguments[1];
                var value;

                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    value = list[i];
                    if (iterator.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
                        return value;
                    }
                }
                return undefined;    
            };
        }

        var theName = myns.dataList.find(function(entry) {
            return entry.name === selfName;
        });

        expect(2 + 2).not.toEqual(4); /* doesn't get here because of TypeError */
    });
 });
```